# Como agregar un atributo, que no viene en el array

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Ok, yo tengo un función que convierte de array plano a un array de objetos json, que pasa, quisiera agregarle un atributo más, en este caso tengo la siguiente función, que procesa el array

```
let data = [
  ["0000001", "PAUL", "Y", "PELUCHE", "DRAKE", "DOG"],
  ["0000002", "ECHEBEL", "Y", "CAT", ""],
  ["0000003", "NANCY", "Y", "FERRET", "HAMSTER", ""]
];

function procesar(data){

let resultado = [];

data.forEach(arreglo => {

  let ref = 'ref'
  let order = 0;
  for(i = 3 ; i < arreglo.length; i++){
    if(arreglo[i].length > 0){
      let obj = {
                service : parseInt(arreglo[0]),
                name : arreglo[1]
           }
      obj[ref] = arreglo[i];
      resultado.push(obj);
    }
  }

});
return resultado;
}console.log(procesar(data))
```

Lo que me retorna actualmente la función

```
[
  { service: 1, name: 'PAUL', ref: 'PELUCHE' },
  { service: 1, name: 'PAUL', ref: 'DRAKE' },
  { service: 1, name: 'PAUL', ref: 'DOG' },
  { service: 2, name: 'ECHEBEL', ref: 'CAT' },
  { service: 3, name: 'NANCY', ref: 'FERRET' },
  { service: 3, name: 'NANCY', ref: 'HAMSTER' }
]
```

Lo que quisiera, que me retornará la función, que procesa el array

```
[
  { service: 1, name: 'PAUL', ref: 'PELUCHE', order:0},
  { service: 1, name: 'PAUL', ref: 'DRAKE', order:1 },
  { service: 1, name: 'PAUL', ref: 'DOG', order:2 },
  { service: 2, name: 'ECHEBEL', ref: 'CAT', order:0 },
  { service: 3, name: 'NANCY', ref: 'FERRET', order:0 },
  { service: 3, name: 'NANCY', ref: 'HAMSTER', order:1 }
]
```

Agradecido con sus comentarios

Comment: En lo que esperas que retorne tu función, tienes un atributo order, pero en la funcionalidad la declaras pero no la usas, como itera esa variable o como deberia iterarse para que te de lo que esperas?

Comment: Quisiera iterar ese atributo hasta el maximo de 2 hasta cuando el service cambiase, es que ese order es un atributo de mi entidad, pero en la funcion donde guardo los datos tampoco sé como interar hasta el 2 y que regrese a 0 cuando cambie el service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacer lo del `order`, en comentarios tienes las explicaciones de lo que hice, intenté hacerlo lo más sencillo posible pero si quieres alguna explicación más no dudes en preguntar:

```js
let data = [
    ["0000001", "PAUL", "Y", "PELUCHE", "DRAKE", "DOG"],
    ["0000002", "ECHEBEL", "Y", "CAT", ""],
    ["0000003", "NANCY", "Y", "FERRET", "HAMSTER", ""]
];

function procesar(data){
    let resultado = [];
    //Añado un par de variables para controlar el nombre y las veces que se ha repetido
    let lastService = "";
    let serviceOrder = 0;

    data.forEach(arreglo => {
        let ref = 'ref'
        let order = 0;
        for(i = 3 ; i < arreglo.length; i++){
            if(arreglo[i].length > 0){
            let obj = {
                        service : parseInt(arreglo[0]),
                        name : arreglo[1]
                }
            obj[ref] = arreglo[i];
            //Comprobamos si el name actual es el mismo que el pasado
            if(arreglo[1] == lastService)
                serviceOrder++;//Si es igual, incrementamos 1
            else
                serviceOrder = 0;//Si no es igual, reseteamos a 0 ya que hemos cambiado de service
            //Asignamos al objeto la variable order con el valor de serviceOrder
            obj.order = serviceOrder;
            //Cambiamos el lastService por el nombre del actual antes de finalizar la iteración
            lastService = arreglo[1];
            resultado.push(obj);
            }
        }
    });
    return resultado;
}
console.log(procesar(data));
```

Como ves, el resultado es exactamente el que esperabas.